# Printing out without using loops

Tags: python

So I have this code

```
city1, city2, city3 = input(), input(), input()

a = max(len(city1), len(city2), len(city3))

b = min(len(city1), len(city2), len(city3))
```

I need to print out a city with max and min len.
Is there a way without using loops?

Comment: Why don't you want to use loops (and a list of cities)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You showed code that doesn't have any loops, and then asked if you can do it without loops?

Answer (score 4):

`min` and `max` have a `key` argument:

```
max((city1, city2, city3), key=len)
```

Comment: Much obliged, my saviour

Comment: It will only return the first string with max/min length. for example, `max(["hello", "world", "me", "he"], key=len)` will only return `hello` and not `world` even though both are of max length

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you can use a `map()` function. (For more information about this function just google it or use the python documentation )

one more thing make sure all your city does not have spaces!

```
city=[input("Your city:"), input("Your city:"), input("Your city:"), input("Your city:"),input("Your city:"), input("Your city:"),input("Your city:")]
print(city)
min_city= min(city)

max_city = max (city)

def search_city_min(x) : 
    if x==min_city:
        print(x)
                            

def search_city_max(x) :
    if x==max_city:
        print(x)                            

list(map(search_city_min,city))

list(map(search_city_max,city))
```